# PHP output specialchars as hex

Tags: php, hex, special-characters

Is there a way to ouput specialchars such as Ampersand `&` as `&#x26;` and not as `&amp;`

When using htmlenties or htmlspecialchars I couldn't find a setting to provide this behaviour.

Any suggestions.

Comment: `bin2hex('&')` would at least give you the 26 part, not sure if that's an avenue of investigation. What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out by myself.
I use mb_ord with is similar to ord except it is for multi-byte codings like UTF-8.
Also it is only working if PHP 7.2 is installed.

```
<?php 
$text = html_entity_decode('&infin;&auml;&euro;&auml;&atilde;&acirc;',ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401,'UTF-8');
$text_converted = '';
for($i=0;$i<mb_strlen($text,'UTF-8');$i++){
    $text_converted .= sprintf('&#x%X;',mb_ord(mb_substr($text,$i,1,'UTF-8')));
}
echo $text_converted;
echo '<br>';
echo str_replace('&','&amp;',$text_converted);
echo '<br>';
echo $text;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `urlencode` then `str_replace` to do that

```
$string = 'Stackoverflow # & " ';  
$string = urlencode($string);    
$find = ['%', '+']; 
$replace = ['&#x', ' '];
$string = str_replace($find,$replace, $string);
echo $string;
```

Comment: I've try it with a different string 'Überschrift Lörüm Ipsûm '  and  the Ü get destroyed. The output is �rschrift Lörüm Ipsûm